# Декомпиляция программы написанной на C#

Tags: c#, reverse-engineering

Добрый день, меня интересует один важный для меня вопрос. Есть программа, 100% написанная на C#. Смог ее декомпилировать программой ILSpy. Код получился неплохой. Есть ли возможность это все скомпилировать, изменив всего 1 значение в коде?

Comment: Возможность есть всегда. Попробуйте.

Comment: Я просто не считаю за возможность копирование всего текста из окошек декомпилятора в проект VS. Это как минимум глупо и банально :). Еще хочу сказать что это не крэкинг, программа куплена мною.

Comment: > это не крэкинг, программа куплена мною

Наличие факта покупки не входит в понятие "крэкинга". Но это не так важно.

Comment: А почему вы нас спрашиваете? У вас есть код, компилируйте, откуда мы знаем, скомпилируется ли он?

Comment: Я не спрашиваю вас скомпилируеться ли он, я спрашиваю: "как это сделать"?

Comment: @Flumm: я правильно понял, вы спрашиваете, как скомпилировать исходники на C#? Если это проблема, вам не сюда.

---
А вообще, для целей типа вашей традиционно используется [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil).

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, вам в этом может помочь утилита ilasm.exe. Запустить вы ее можете через командную строку Visual Studio (Пуск => Все проргаммы => Visual Studio => Visual Studio Tools => Visual Studio Command Prompt). Ей нужно скормить il-файл, из которого она сможет собрать exe-файл.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Вы очень помогли. "Наградил" тем, что было :).

Comment: ну зачем такие самопожертвования)) Пожалуйста))

Comment: Прошу прощения, а как я могу получить этот il-файл? :)

Comment: ну вы же говрите, что с помощью вашей ILSpy смогли декомпилировать программу. Разве у вас не il-файл получился? Ну во всяком случае, можете воспользоваться утилитой ildasm.exe, которая находится там же, где и ilasm. Эта утилита делает обратное - из exe-файла генерирует il

Comment: ILSpy показал код внутри себя, так сказать :). Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

.NET Reflector позволяет экспортировать результаты декомпиляции в проект Visual Studio.

P.S.: Бесплатную версию можно найти в сети.

Comment: Еще раз, спасибо! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Еще хочу сказать что это не крэкинг,
> программа куплена мною.

Даже факт покупки не дает вам право на реверс инжиниринг. Я не знаю ни одной коммерческой лицензии, которая разрешает реверс инжиниринг купленной программы.

Comment: Я имею право использовать эту программу в некоммерческих  целях, на своем личном компьютере как хочу, хоть сделаю из нее графичеческий редактор, а в нем сделаю картинку, распечатаю все это на принтере, драйвер которого я переписал и повешу это у себя дома на стену. И это будет законно.

Comment: @Barmaley: законодательство некоторых стран [разрешает](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering#Legality) реверс-инжиниринг и декомпиляцию.

Comment: В этой стране декомпиляция и анализ в личных целях тоже разрешены.

Comment: О чем, собственно я и говорил в своем комментарии. В любой стране можно делать то, о чем я говорил. В случае со мной, то я делаю это для себя и не собираюсь выкладывать это в паблик, а значит это законно ^_^.